# how to search a list of values in another list

Tags: python

I'am new in Python.
Is there a way to search a list of values (words and fraises) in another list (csv table), and get only the matched rows?

Example:

LiastOfValues=['smoking','hard smoker','alcoholic']

```
ListfromCSV =
ID,TYPE,STRING1,NUMBER
1, a,'this is hard smoker man',4
2, b,'this one likes to drink',5
3, c,'dont like sigarets',6
4, e,'this one is smoking',7
```

To search LiastOfValues in each row and reply only the matched rows.

```
The Output:
```

```
Output=
ID,TYPE,STRING1,NUMBER
1, a,'this is hard smoker man',4
4, e,'this one is smoking',7
```

```
I have tryed this:
```

```
import csv

ListfromCSV ="ListfromCSV.txt"
LiastOfValues=['smoking','hard smoker','alcoholic','smoker']

with open(ListfromCSV ,'r') as f:
    LineReader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    for i in LineReader: 
        if value in (i[2])) :
            print (i)
```

Comment: Is the list from the csv a nested one?

Comment: You should include working code of what you have tried so far

Comment: The `in` operator is what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It assumes your csv is not nested and contains strings. If it is nested, you can convert the lists to strings:

```
[row for row in csv if any(map(lambda x: x in row,LiastOfValues))]
```

This code should get a list with matched rows (does not include header unless you match it)